# ExtJS 4 - Inner component not resizing in fit layout after resize with resizeHandles

Tags: javascript, html, extjs4.2

I have a few panels, I can drag them and place them to other places. Some of them have resizeHandles to change its height manually. If I drag a panel and place somewhere where the width is smaller than the panel and also its children (toolbar, header etc) are changing the width. But when I change the height then drag a panel like written above, then only the main panels width is changing, the children are staying on the same size. A panel looks something like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    layout: 'fit',
    resizable: true,
    resizeHandles: 's',
    draggable: {
            moveOnDrag: false
    },
    items: [
        toolbar or panel or container (depends on the panel)
    ]
}
```

I was thinking about, that it's changing something in the layout after resize, but I couldn't find anything. I tried to debug it but it's almost impossible the find out whats wrong. Tried doLayout(), doComponentLayout() but nothing seems to work. Now I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I was debugging this problem for a very long time and I found out, that after resizing the panel with resizeHandles they're getting a width property, and after drag it's somehow influencing the panel so it won't resize.
The solution was to delete the width property right after the resize and now it works fine.

**EDIT:**

The listeners part of the code is the solution. Maybe not the best way, but it works.

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    layout: 'fit',
    resizable: true,
    resizeHandles: 's',
    draggable: {
            moveOnDrag: false
    },
    items: [
        toolbar or panel or container (depends on the panel)
    ],
    listeners: {
            resize: function(component, ...) {
                    delete component.width;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please get us the exact code you wrote to solve this problem?